# TeamCity: Clear out publish directory AFTER successful build

Tags: teamcity, build-server

I am trying to get TeamCity to clear out the publish directory on a remote server AFTER a successful build on the build server. I want this to work like a clean checkout does on the build server. The workflow should be:

1. Checkout
2. Build
3. Clear Publish Directory
4. Publish successful build files to Publish Directory

Comment: Can you have 'publish' as a separate build config, depending on successful build of 'build' config?

Answer (score -2):

In TeamCity 8.x, workflows like this can be done using the conditional-execute option on build steps within a config.  Your "Clear Publish Directory" build step could set the "Execute step:" option to "If all previous steps finished successfully (zero exit code)".  And similarly for build step 4.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. -1